# multiple definition error when building C++ project with makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Please go through the entire question before marking it as already answered.

I am a beginner and learning coding all by myself, this question might seem dumb to expert developers but I have nobody else to help me out but the online community. I tried searching for an answer but did not got a specific one due to which I am stuck on it.

I am creating a simple project for learning to use make files and I keep getting multiple definitions error.

Below is the code for **`Makefile`**

```
all: vecy

vecy: main1.o vec.o
    g++ -o vecy main1.o vec.o

main1.o: main1.cpp vec.h
    g++ -c main1.cpp

vec.o: vec.cpp vec.h
    g++ -c vec.cpp

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o vecy
```

Below are the **`Errors`** which I get on executing the Makefile

```
g++ -o vecy main1.o vec.o
vec.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `vec'
main1.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
vec.o:(.bss+0x18): multiple definition of `sum'
main1.o:(.bss+0x18): first defined here
vec.o:(.bss+0x20): multiple definition of `i'
main1.o:(.bss+0x20): first defined here
vec.o:(.bss+0x24): multiple definition of `n'
main1.o:(.bss+0x24): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:4: recipe for target 'vecy' failed
make: *** [vecy] Error 1
```

Below is the code for **`main1.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vec.h"

int main(){
input();
print();
}
```

Below is the code for **`vec.h`**

```
#include <vector>

#ifndef vec_h
#define vec_h

std::vector<int> vec;

long long int sum;

int i, n;

void input();
void print();

#endif
```

Below is the code for **`vec.cpp`**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vec.h"

using namespace std;

void input(){

cout << "Enter the number of elements you want to enter into the vector = ";
cin >> n;

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
int alpha;  cin >> alpha;
sum += alpha;
vec.push_back(alpha);
}
}

void print(){

cout << "elements entered into the vector are\n\n";

for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << vec[i] << "  ";
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Sum of elements entered in the vector = " << sum << endl;

}
```

where is the problem? I have only defined `vec` `sum` `i` and `n` once in the header file `vec.h`and it has file guards in place so must not be getting included twice.

Would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defining declarations of the variables (`vec`, `sum`, `i` & `n`) should be done in an implementation file (.cpp file) to avoid the compiler seeing multiple definitions of the same variable. Otherwise one of the key language rule is violated which is known as ODR(**One Definition Rule**).

Since both of your .cpp files(`main.cpp` & `vec.cpp`) include `vec.h` file, the object files generated via the translation units will see multiple definitions of those variables if they were defined in the header files.

Move the variable definitions from the `vec.h` to `vec.cpp` file and see the issue gets evaporated.

To further clarify, have the following lines moved to `vec.cpp` file.

```
std::vector<int> vec;

long long int sum;

int i, n;
```

Comment: You left out that the header file still needs declarations if other code files need access. That would look like `extern long long int sum;`

Comment: @ZanLynx True, but only if he needs. As per the example there's no need to keep the defining declarations in the header therefore, no need to use `extern`.